# Setting up a tab host with only an Activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am new to android programming and i have been at this issue for 3weeks, i need to move on. How can i setup 3 Tab-host with only an activity without extending the activity and i don't want to use Fragment or a Tab-activity. I want each tab to have separate activity within them, i have looked through different tutorials and no direct answer has been provided a lot of what i find has been depreciated, i will appreciate it, if example can be given or a tutorial. Please Help!! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Activity will definitely solve your problem. But still if you want you can always go for fragments.

this is tutorial for tab host>>>
http://www.technotalkative.com/android-iphone-like-tab-bar-in-android/

Comment: http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/
this is tutorial for tab host using Fragments.
Good luck!

Comment: Pratik, this tutorial extends fragment i just want to use activity and allow each tab have its only activity within them

Comment: I think you have to use FragmentActivity and use use the v4 support library to support older version.

Comment: vins thank you for your contribution, but must i use FragmentActivity, i would like to know if there is another way to use activity alone, i have been at the cross-road for 3weeks now,its frustrating

Comment: Please i need help am stock, for 3weeks!! I just want to use activity alone for my tabhost and each tab is to have its own activity.A tutorial will be helpful. Thank you